# Java Decompiler generates abstract enum

Tags: java

I used JD to decompile a .jar executable file. I encountered an abstract enum code which does not compile:

```
private static abstract enum Type {
    ANONYMOUS(4) , STANDARD(0);

    private final int start;

    private Type(int start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public int getStart() {
        return this.start;
    }

    public abstract void insertHeader(Sheet paramSheet,
            SummaryCodec.Style paramStyle, float paramFloat1,
            float paramFloat2);

    public abstract String insertCommentSource(String paramString);

    public abstract int insertBreakdown(Sheet paramSheet,
            SummaryCodec.Style paramStyle, String paramString,
            Entry paramEntry, int paramInt);

    public abstract void collateComment(List<String> paramList,
            String paramString);
}
```

Compiler errors:
Illegal modifier for the member enum Type; only public, protected, private & static are permitted
The enum constant ANONYMOUS must implement the abstract method collateComment(List, String)
The enum constant STANDARD must implement the abstract method collateComment(List, String)

Where can I find the code for the implementations of the abstract methods for ANONYMOUS, and STANDARD? I can't find it in the same file. Tried looking for it in other files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JD apparently has a bug decompiling enums with abstract methods; you shouldn't get that class signature (which does correspond to the bytecode but doesn't take into account the magic the Java compiler does with `enum`).

Each enum instance that overrides a method declared gets its own `.class` file, just as anonymous classes do. Look for files named like `Type$1.class` in the same directory as `Type.class`.

Comment: Thanks for the info on JD. Unfortunately, I can't find any class of that file name in any of the subdirectories shown in JD's explorer.

Comment: I extracted the JAR file and found the files! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Making an abstract enum does not make sense as you will definitely have instances.
In fact ANONYMOUS and STANDARD are instances of the enum Type which also why the compiler tells you that you have to implement the abstract method insertCommentSource.

I have no idea why the decompiler produced this code but i am very sure that this does not conform to Java language specifications! Also it does not make sense ;)

Comment: Enums that have abstract methods produce an abstract base class for the enum itself and then anonymous classes for the enum instances.

Comment: Fair enough but then the implementation of insertCommentSource is still missing the anonymous implementations ANONYMOUS and STANDARD. Still ... why the hell would you want to do it this way?

Comment: First, watch the language; second, having abstract methods implemented for each enum instance specifically is a very useful idiom.

Comment: Want to do *what* this way? This is a deficiency in the way JD decompiles enums that are compiled with certain features, and the implementations were all present in the original source code.